# A $2$ form on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, self-learning

I am self-studying Differential geometry by Loring Tu. I am stuck on this question.  Edit: Is it just $p^3 dx \wedge dy$ ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not quite, but almost. Try plugging in some examples.

Comment: @mfl How do you compute it systematically ? Can you add an answer?

Comment: @Thorgott I have edited my answer is this correct?

Comment: No. Have you tried plugging in some examples?

Comment: I don't like examples. I like the most general answer using the theory. I will try plugging in some examples.

Comment: I think this is correct.

Comment: @Thorgott I have edited it. I think this agrees with examples?

Comment: @Thorgott can you tell me how can I compute it for general ones instead of trial and error ? I think this comes from the computation that wedge product of k-covectors is the determinant right ? This how I was able to guess the answer. Maybe if you add a general answer I will accept it.

Comment: Yes, this is correct now. This does indeed come from the relationship between wedges and determinants. What kind of general answer are you looking for? How to compute the components of an arbitrary 2-form in the standard basis?

Comment: Yes. Given everything is written arbitrary. I just want to see all the details myself. I have written out myself. I would like to compare. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the hints and solutions to selected problems at the end of Tu's book? The problem you have above is discussed there.

Comment: oh man, I thought he only answers with asterisks on it. Though solving it myself clarified things.

Comment: I looked at the answer very different than mine, though we got the same thing. I mentioned how I got my answer.

Comment: Take a loot at Proposition 3.29 and its proof again for the general case.